# setup of 5 figures as 2x3 table with 6th cell having the caption

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I want the figure to look like the following. Cant figure out how to do that using graphicx or subfloat. :s

[image: The way it should look like]

please help :)

After the discussions:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Fig3a}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Fig3b}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Fig3c}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Fig3d}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Fig3e}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{caption stuff}
\end{minipage}%
\label{fig3}
\end{figure}
```

but this still gives the caption at the end and not in the 6th box

FYI: I am using the svjour3 document

Also now I think if the fig 3 a comes alone and bcde come in a 2x2 pattern would be the best.

OK I finally did the above using the tabular

Thanks ppl :)

Comment: Since you don't need captions for each of the images that compose the figure, using subfloats is unnecessary, and you can easily produce the result you want with a two-column `tabular` environment...

Comment: Do you mean to make a table and put the includegraphics commands inside as columns?

Comment: I wrote that first comment too fast. `\caption` causes problems if used "naked" in a `tabular` cell. Putting it in a `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}`, as in Harish Kumar's answer, solves obviates those problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should get you started. As mentioned by jubobs, since you don't need captions for individual figures, you don't need `subfig` (or `subcaption`)

Using `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  &
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  &
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  &\multicolumn{1}{b{.4\linewidth}}{\caption{Caption text coming here at the last position}}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{Caption text coming here at the last position}
\end{minipage}%

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @jubobs, Thanks for the typo eradication :-)

Comment: Well guys (and Hopefully gals :) )....... the first idea doesnt compile at least in my tex..... and the second one gives the caption at the end instead of in 6th box :(

Comment: @ankhi: Can you post your code in your question? As such we can't tell what is the problem.

Comment: \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Fig5a}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Fig5b}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Fig5c}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Fig5d}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Fig5e}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{stuff}
\end{minipage}%
\label{fig5}
\end{figure}

Comment: @ankhi Please post the code in the question itself. And please make it complete with `\documentclass{...}` to `\end{document}` like in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what I finally ended up doing

\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[natbib,fleqn,smallextended]{svjour3}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]

\begin{tabular}{cc}

\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{1}} \
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{2} &
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{3}\
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{4} &
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{5}

\end{tabular}

\caption{These sketches are very well drawn}

\label{fig}

\end{figure}

\end{document}

The look:

[image: Made sense]